# How to get an array from another class from Score.java to Test.java

Tags: java

hello I want to pass the an array of marks from another class called Score which is in Score.java.
I am using JDK.
and absolute beginner.

```
public class test {
     public static void main (String[] args)
     { 
        System.out.print("Hello");
        test(Score.testMarks);
     }

     public static void test(Score.testMarks){
         System.out.print(testMarks[n] + " ");
     }
}
```

when i build the program, it is saying `error: <identifier> expected`
How do I have to do?

All I want is to get the array from Score class from Score.java to Test.java

Thanks alot

Comment: Correct this : `public static void test(Score[] testMarks)`

Comment: change `public static void test(Score.testMarks)` to `public static void test(Object[] testMarks)`

Comment: What is this `testMarks[n]`? Where have you defined `n`?

Comment: The value of `n` is not defined in the argument list for the `test` method. Also, the testMarks argument of the `test` method is not defined properly--it should be something like `double[] testMarks` or some other array type.

Comment: You should be getting a line number with your error message. That's a critical piece of information that you will always use to find your errors.

Comment: Thanks alot.. I have figured out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why you get the error:

`public static void test(Score.testMarks)`

You should change it to:

`public static void test(Score[] testMarks)`

(I suggest you to read the [Defining Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) toturial).

Since you're doing `System.out.print(testMarks[n] + " ");` then I believe `testMarks` is an array of type `Score`. And that's written as `Score[]` in Java.

You have another errors, I'm not sure what are you trying to do in this method. What is `n`? What did you mean to do?

Comment: `System.out.print(testMarks[n] + " ");` should also prevent the compiler from compiling!!